# Loop through JSON nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

With this JSON object:

```
{
  "date_price": [
    {
      "date": "Jan 2000",
      "price": 1394.46
    },
    {
      "date": "Feb 2000",
      "price": 1366.42
    },
    {
      "date": "Mar 2000",
      "price": 1498.58
    },
    {
      "date": "Apr 2000",
      "price": 1452.43
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I loop through it and save each pair date-price in a simple array, using something like this, for example:

```
var transformation = [];

transformation.push({date: i, price: d})
```

Because the problem here is that in the console, when I print the JSON object, it says they are objects inside of the array, so I can't use the `forEach()` loop

Comment: You can not `loop` `JSON`, you will need `JavaScript-object(array)`

Comment: Can you show us how the transformed object would be like? Because I think it's already in the same intended form.

Comment: It's already stored that exact way in the `date_price` array key.
Simply refer to the key `var transformation = obj.date_price;`

Comment: You can use map and forEach on array regardless of content

Comment: The JSON is stored inside a variable when my service returns the request.

Comment: @RyanWillis: No, that's for a JavaScript object.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3271/

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes: That is not JSON. _Sigh_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit if he's printing the JSON object in the console and it's stating that there are objects inside of the array, the given variable is not a JSON string, but a JavaScript object.

Comment: @RyanWillis: Precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've parsed the JSON to an object...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

...[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the data.

> Note: instead of an array of objects (as you ask for in your question) based on your response to my question you want a nested array structure instead.

ES5

```
var transformation = obj.date_price.map(function(el) {
  return [ el.date, el.price ];
});
```

ES6

```
var transformation = obj.date_price.map(el => [ el.date, el.price ]);
```

OUTPUT

```
[
  ["Jan 2000", 1394.46],
  ["Feb 2000", 1366.42],
  ["Mar 2000", 1498.58],
  ["Apr 2000", 1452.43]
]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/v79uwe5b/3/)

Comment: Using that way, it is returning [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object], I just want the simple pair date-price

Comment: @Shoplifter20: What do you think a pair is?

Comment: Do you mean an nested array `[['Apr 2000', 1452.43]...]` instead @Shoplifter20?

Comment: Yes, that's it, sorry for the mistake

Comment: @Shoplifter20, in future explicitly add your expected output to your question and save lots of people their time in answering a question you didn't want answered.

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes, actually your answer provides an array of objects in an array - not the same thing.

Comment: you're right.. I was just talking about the type of return not being json.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as you already have the JSON as an object, then you merely need to get the date_price property from it. That's an array of exactly the object types you require... so...

```
var result = jsonObject.date_price; // THIS is your array here.
```

Or...

```
var result = jsonObject['date_price']; // THIS is your array here.
```

---

**Previous answer given, which assumes a JSON string...**

Simply using this...

```
// This is just your JSON string above.
var text = '{ "date_price": [ { "date": "Jan 2000", "price": 1394.46 }, { "date": "Feb 2000", "price": 1366.42 }, { "date": "Mar 2000", "price": 1498.58 }, { "date": "Apr 2000", "price": 1452.43 } ] }';

// Parse it as an object.
var obj = JSON.parse(text);

// Get the date_price property, which is an array already.
var result = obj.date_price;

// Some output here, to illustrate...
console.log(result);
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Shoplifter20: Response from what? You never mentioned any "response" in your question. So your code actually receives a JavaScript object, not JSON? Could you be clear please?

Comment: If you've already got an object, then simply omit that part about parsing the string. You merely need to get the date_price property from your JSON object, in that case. If you wish to loop through that array and push those elements into a separate array, then that's up to you, but you don't really need to as you've already got an array with the same property naming convention in the object you have already.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `JSON.parse` and `Array.map` functions:

```js
var jsonStr = '{"date_price": [{ "date": "Jan 2000", "price": 1394.46 },{"date": "Feb 2000",      "price": 1366.42},{"date": "Mar 2000","price": 1498.58},{"date": "Apr 2000","price": 1452.43}]}',
    jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

//var transformation = jsonObj["date_price"]; // to get a nested array

var transformation = jsonObj["date_price"].map(function(v){ return v; }); // to perform test artificial loop
    
document.write("<pre>"+ JSON.stringify(transformation, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: `.map(function(v){ return v; })` is essentially a no-op.

Comment: @georg, I know, but the author said "How can I loop through it", and I thought he wanted to perform an artificial loop (Of course, he could get the array just with `transformation = jsonObj["date_price"]`).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var abc = {
 "date_price": [
{
  "date": "Jan 2000",
  "price": 1394.46
},
{
  "date": "Feb 2000",
  "price": 1366.42
},
{
  "date": "Mar 2000",
  "price": 1498.58
},
{
  "date": "Apr 2000",
  "price": 1452.43
}
]
}
var array = $.map(abc, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/3271/

Comment: what json? @LightnessRacesinOrbit I tested the code and it runs without any problem.

Comment: http://json.org It's a text interchange format. Your code runs fine but it bears no relationship to the question as currently written.

Comment: I know what json is.. I just don't see why this is not correct. his object is there **abc** and the created object as he asked is being generated there.

Comment: If you don't see why this is not correct, then you _don't_ know what JSON is.

Comment: unless you are talking about the result, then I need to read about what json is. because he didn't ask the result in json.

Comment: Also, jQuery? The OP isn't using it and it's not necessary.

Comment: Question title: _"Loop through JSON nested array"_ First line of question: _"With this JSON object:"_ Later in the question: _"when I print the JSON object"_ Don't get me wrong, I don't think the OP understands what JSON is, either.

Comment: @Andy it was not told that I couldn't use jquery. well.. I think the problem is with the question.. because I followed his example. loop through JSON for me would loop through the abc in my code.. which is a JSON. I don't see he asking result in json.. but.. what can I do.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution. It's already in the format you need. You just need to remove the nesting.

```
var obj = {
  "date_price": [
    {
      "date": "Jan 2000",
      "price": 1394.46
    },
    {
      "date": "Feb 2000",
      "price": 1366.42
    },
    {
      "date": "Mar 2000",
      "price": 1498.58
    },
    {
      "date": "Apr 2000",
      "price": 1452.43
    }
  ]
};

var array = obj['date_price'];
```

And that's it.

Comment: Sorry modified my solution to include setting the json in a variable.

Comment: OP said "With this JSON object:" then posts a javascript object, not JSON.  It wasn't clear what he was working with because he said one thing and posted another.  Using the code OP provided doesn't seem worthy of -1.

Comment: Still not seeing any JSON here mate

Comment: @IrkenInvader: I see no evidence that OP "posts a javascript object". Looks like a verbatim block of JSON to me. I'll -1 whenever an answer doesn't answer the question posed. I can remove the downvote if the OP reveals that their question was unclear and they meant a JavaScript object.

Comment: With this code if you change any data in the original object array it will be reflected in the new array which probably isn't what the OP wants as a side-effect.

Comment: My backend is using the jsonify to transform it to JSON

Comment: @Shoplifter20: You're making drive-by references to bunch of functions performed by other parts of your system, and all those references remain entirely unexplained. No matter, abstract them away. Consider _only_ what the code you're asking about actually receives from wherever it receives it.